# Given $x_n$, $y_n=a+1-x_n$, Find the limit of $\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}$

Tags: limits

**My problem**

Given $a>0$, $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ such that
\begin{cases}
x_0=0\\
x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n+a(a+1)}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}

- Prove that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=a+1$
- $y_n=a+1-x_n$, Find the limit of $\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}$

**My attempts**

*First question*: straight out easy!. If $x_n<a+1$ then $a+1>x_{n+1} > x_n$ and thus $(x_n)$ ascends and bounded above. Thus it has a limit, which could also be solved out easily $L=a+1$. Otherwise ($x_n>a+1$), the solution is similar with $(x_n)$ bounded below.

*Second question*: What I did was that:
\begin{align}
a+1-x_{n+1}=a+1-\sqrt{x_n+a(a+1)}\\=\frac{a+1-x_n}{a+1+\sqrt{x_n+a(a+1)}}\end{align}
thus \begin{align}\boxed{\lim{\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}}=\frac1{2(a+1)}}\end{align}

Is that true? I doubt my solution to the second problem. If not, what's the solution?

Comment: The second part is correct. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @markvs because I wasn't sure about $\frac00$, as $a+1-x_n \to 0$, you know...

Comment: Everything bad cancels.

Comment: I dont think the second part is wrong. About 0/0, take for example the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x+x^2}{x}=1$$ where the denominator and numerator go to 0 when $x$ tends to 0.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't find anything wrong with the algebra. Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: My apologies! I wasn't thinking. The second part is correct.